# Acessing an object

Tags: javascript, jquery

The user gives various entries in the fields. Then when he pushes the create button I wrote a function test() to create a hero object with the users entries. But when I try to access the hero object with the button check your hero I get

> mainCharacter (=name of the individualized Hero object)is not defined

What am I doing wrong? How do I get the mainCharacter Object out of the test() function?

I tried numerous return statements of the mainCharacter object within the test() function.

```js
function Hero(name, power, endurance, lives, workedout) {
  this.name = name;
  this.power = power;
  this.endurance = endurance;
  this.lives = lives;
  this.workedout = workedout;
}

// Create the hero function; takes the values from the players entries except for workedout;

function test() {
  var name1 = $("#heroName").val();
  var power1 = document.getElementById("heroPower").value;
  var endurance1 = $("#heroEndurance").val();
  var lives1 = document.getElementById("heroLives").value;
  var workedout1 = false;

  // CHECK IF THERE`s a STRING IN HERO NAME

  switch (isNaN(name1) || parseInt(name1)) {
    case true:
      alert("Everything ok");
      break;
    default:
      alert("Please enter a name");
      break;
  }

  var mainCharacter = new Hero(name1, power1, endurance1, lives1, workedout1);


  alert("His name is " + mainCharacter.name + " his power is " + mainCharacter.power + " his endurance is " + mainCharacter.endurance + " and his lives are " + mainCharacter.lives);
  return mainCharacter;

};

function alertHero() {
  alert(mainCharacter.lives);
}
```

```html
<h1>Create your hero</h1>

Your hero`s name <input type="text" name="name" id="heroName"> Your hero`s power <input type="number" name="power" id="heroPower"> Your hero`s endurance <input type="number" name="endurance" id="heroEndurance"> Your hero`s lives <input type="number" name="lives"
  id="heroLives">

<button onclick="test()"> Create </button>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<button onclick="alertHero()"> Check your hero  </button>
```

Comment: `mainCharacter` is not defined in the scope that `alertHero` has access to (which is the global scope). `test` returns an object but you are not doing anything with it. *"How do I get the mainCharacter Object out of the test() function?"* Given the way your code is written, you can assign it to a global variable: `window.mainCharacter = test();`.

Comment: looks like you never stored mainCharacter anywhere

Comment: So what shall I do???

Comment: Want to create an Object out of the users entries

Comment: either store it as a global variable or in a closure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope). A quick fix might be something like this:

```
var mainCharacter;

...

function test() {
    // same as your old code
    mainCharacter = new Hero(...);
}

function alertHero() {
    alert(mainCharacter.lives);
}
```